# How do I edit disclaimer/contact information?

Tags: author, editor, contact, wp-create-user, authorization

I inherited this wordpress website called RxStudyGuides to use as a study tool for pharmacy students. However, the owner and creator of the website still has there contact information on the website at the bottom of the page and I can't seem to find how to edit that information. It only seems that I can edit the actual content of the website. The creator made me an editor and maybe since I am not the owner of the site I cannot edit information other than content? If that is the case is there a way to transfer ownership of the site?

Answer (score 0):

The contents that existing in the header and footer that is the content that visible in all pages will usually integrate using theme option. so  take the admin and  go to  appearance->Theme option Then check the contact details is there in that .

Comment: Hello, thank you for responding. There is not an option to modify the theme/appearance. I only have the options to manage: site pages, blog posts, media, comments, feedback, and sharing. Like I said I'm not sure I have full editing capabilities because I am not the creator of the site. i have admin access to another site and I can see the options to "personalize" and edit admin/editors, however these are lacking with my RxStudyGuides site. Is there a way to transfer admin access from the creator of the site to me?

Comment: Update: I copied the URL https://wordpress.com/customize/rxstudyguidesuic.wordpress.com to go to what would be the customize page and it says I don't have permission to customize the site.

Comment: in that case i think you don't have the access in database too. Don't you....    if you have the db access you can simply search the content in db and update your new content in the contact information area.

Comment: one more possibility  is there, that is  contact information is in the footer,sometimes he put the contact details as static in the code itself...